# In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?

Tags: java, xml, string, file, parsing

I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);
```

How can I get it to parse XML contained within a String instead of a file?

Comment: Also note that `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(string)` assumes the string is a uri (terrible...)

Answer (score 520, accepted):

I have this function in my code base, this should work for you.

```
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262)

Comment: @shsteimer I am passing in xml string and it is returning null. It does not throw any exception. What must be wrong?

Comment: @sattu: You should post it as a new question. It's really hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: thanks much, saved me bunch lines of code, i was converting it back to text but I knew there was a better way!

Comment: if I have <?XML> it returns an empty node what can i do?

Comment: Check that you use the right import statement: `import org.xml.sax.InputSource;`

Comment: For me, parse() takes InputStream, not InputSource

Comment: Why is everything in Java so gross? Seriously?

Answer (score 20):

One way is to use the version of parse that takes an InputSource rather than a file

A SAX InputSource can be constructed from a Reader object. One Reader object is the StringReader

So something like

```
parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(myString))) may work.
```

Answer (score 8):

Convert the string to an InputStream and pass it to DocumentBuilder

```
final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
builder.parse(stream);
```

**EDIT**
In response to **bendin**'s comment regarding encoding, see **shsteimer**'s answer to this question.

Comment: I'd prefer the StringReader because it avoids String.getBytes(), but this should *usually* work also.

Comment: When you call getBytes(), what encoding are you expecting it to use? How are you telling to the XML parser which encoding it's getting? Do you expect it to guess? What happens when you are on a platform where the default encoding isn't UTF-8?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this method

```
public Document parseXmlFromString(String xmlString){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream inputStream = new    ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
    org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
    return document;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) show that the parse method is overloaded.

Create a StringStream or InputSource using your string XML and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scilca XML Progession package available at GitHub.

```
XMLIterator xi = new VirtualXML.XMLIterator("<xml />");
XMLReader xr = new XMLReader(xi);
Document d = xr.parseDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
File f = new File(sac.getFileName());
    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument();

        // root
        Element root = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_ROOT);
        doc.appendChild(root);

        for(Person p: persons){
            // people element
            Element item = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_ELEMENT);
            root.appendChild(item);

            Element name = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_NAME);
            name.setTextContent(p.getName());
            item.appendChild(name);

            Element gender = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_GENDER);
            gender.setTextContent(p.getGender());
            item.appendChild(gender);

            Element age = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_AGE);
            age.setTextContent(String.valueOf(p.getAge()));
            item.appendChild(age);

            Element occ = doc.createElement(Person.KEY_OCCUPATION);
            occ.setTextContent(p.getOccupation());
            item.appendChild(occ);
        }

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");

        // INDENT the xml file is optional, you can
        // uncomment the following statement if you would like the xml files to be more
        // readable
        // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

use following code to load file

```
File f = new File(lc.getFileName());
    if (!f.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(f);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_ELEMENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nList.item(i);
            Person person = new Person();

            if (element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_NAME).item(0) != null)
                person.setName(element.getElementsByTagName(person.KEY_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());

            if (element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_AGE).item(0) != null)
                person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_AGE).item(0).getTextContent()));

            if (element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_OCCUPATION).item(0) != null)
                person.setOccupation(element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_OCCUPATION).item(0).getTextContent());

            if (element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_GENDER).item(0) != null)
                person.setGender(element.getElementsByTagName(Person.KEY_GENDER).item(0).getTextContent());

            persons.add(person);
        }

        this.db.save(lc.getKey(), persons);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```