# Count XML Elements, which are saved as a String

Tags: java, xml

how is it possible with java, to count the number of PolylinePoint elements in this xml snippet (important for you is the fact, that this xml is not a file but a string):

```
    <LocationInformationRequest>
            <InitialInput>
                <GeoRestriction>
                    <Area>
                        <PolylinePoint>
                            <Longitude>88.1</Longitude>
                            <Latitude>88.2</Latitude>
                            <Altitude>88.3</Altitude>
                        </PolylinePoint>
                        <PolylinePoint>
                            <Longitude>88.4</Longitude>
                            <Latitude>88.5</Latitude>
                            <Altitude>88.6</Altitude>
                        </PolylinePoint>
                        <PolylinePoint>
                            <Longitude>88.7</Longitude>
                            <Latitude>88.8</Latitude>
                            <Altitude>88.9</Altitude>
                        </PolylinePoint>
                    </Area>
                </GeoRestriction>
            </InitialInput>
        </LocationInformationRequest>
```

With xml as a file it is easy to solve this problem. But with a string it is more difficult. Any ideas?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: What's the problem about doing it with a string? I think you can parse an XML string as well as a file with the common Java XML APIs. What have you tried so far and how are you currently doing this with a file?

Comment: You might find [this link to the official java tutorials about XML parsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- I guess you'd like to parse your string as XML ? Explained here:
  [In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file)
- Another solution but really **ugly**: if you are 100% sure of your XML structure (and sure that it won't change), you may as well count there number of "`<PolylinePoint`"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:

```
        String str="<PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint><PolylinePoint><Longitude>88.7</Longitude><Latitude>88.8</Latitude><Altitude>88.9</Altitude></PolylinePoint>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<PolylinePoint>");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
        int res=0;
        while (m.find()) {
            res++;
        }
        System.out.println(res++);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating Document drom String?

Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );

Then you can easilly use xPath.