# How to keep character "&" from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'd just written a java file using Eclipse encoding with ISO-8859-1.
In this file, I want to create a String such like that (in order to create a XML content and save it into a database) :

```
//   <image>&lt;img src="path_of_picture"&gt;</image>
String xmlContent = "<image><img src=\"" + path_of_picture+ "\"></image>";
```

In another file, I get this String and create a new String with this constructor :

```
String myNewString = new String(xmlContent.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

In order to be understood by a XML parser, my XML content must be converted to :

```
<image>&lt;img src="path_of_picture"&gt;</image>
```

Unfortunately, I can't find how to write xmlContent to get this result in myNewString. 
I tried two methods :

```
       // First : 
String xmlContent = "<image><img src=\"" + content + "\"></image>"; 
// But the result is just myNewString = <image><img src="path_of_picture"></image>
// and my XML parser can't get the content of <image/>

    //Second :
String xmlContent = "<image>&lt;img src=\"" + content + "\"&gt;</image>";
// But the result is just myNewString = <image>&amp;lt;img src="path_of_picture"&amp;gt;</image>
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Which xml parser u are using? I do not think that '<' or '>' symbols in any form inside the string would be parsed by any one of the parsers.

Comment: How is this related to text encodings? The & character is ASCII, so it's encoded the same in UTF-8 and iso-8859-1, no possibility for confusion there.

Comment: Your problem is more likely related to character escaping, rather than encoding. Do you know about [CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)?

Comment: That's what I thought, but the value of the text is different from the original String when I save it into my database.

Comment: I didn't know CDATA. I'll try with it

Comment: That's a good way. It works !

Answer (score 0):

This is unclear. But Strings don't have an encoding. So when you write

```
String s = new String(someOtherString.getBytes(), someEncoding);
```

you will get various results depending on your default encoding setting (which is used for the `getBytes()` method).

If you want to read a file encoded with ISO-8859-1, you simply do:

- read the bytes from the file: `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);`
- create a string using the file's encoding: `String content = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1);`

If you need to write back the file with a UTF-8 encoding you do:

- convert the string to bytes with UTF-8 encoding: `byte[] utfBytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8");`
- write the bytes to the file: `Files.write(path, utfBytes);`

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel that your question is related to encoding but if you want to "create a String such like that (in order to create a XML content and save it into a database)", you can use this code:

```
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        return builder.parse(is);
    }
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562207/1291122) SO answer.

Comment: That's not exactly my aim, but I have used CDATA and it works.