# Java parse XML with many levels

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a complex xml string that i have to parse i retrieve some data, here is the content :

```
<root1>
    <root2>
        <A>something</A>
        <B>something</B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <GetE>DataE</GetE>
                <GetF>DataF</GetF>
                <G>something</G>
                <H>something</H>
                <I>
                    <J>
                      <GetK>DataK</GetK>
                      <GetL>DataL</GetL>
                    </J>
                </I>
            </D>
            <D>
                <GetE>DataE</GetE>
                <GetF>DataF</GetF>
                <G>something</G>
                <H>something</H>
                <I>
                    <J>
                      <GetK>DataK</GetK>
                      <GetL>DataL</GetL>
                    </J>
                </I>
            </D>
        </C>
     </root2>
</root1>
```

I would like to print the content of `GetE`, `GetF`, `GetK` and `GetL` :

for example :

GetE = DataE,GetF = DataF,GetK = DataK,GetL = DataL

GetE = DataE,GetF = DataF,GetK = DataK,GetL = DataL

...

To convert my String data to an XML, I use this function [In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file)

Any idea please ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select all the nodes with those names, as in an XPath expression?

Comment: What do you mean "multiple roots"? This document, like any XML document, doesn't have multiple root elements; that's what makes the root element a root element.

Comment: I want to get for example : DataE, DataF, DataK, DataL, @chrylis : i would say multiple levels .. it's a mistake

Comment: There should be a tag #dohomeworkforme

Comment: I'm sorry for the sarcastic comment. You did manage to simplify your test case into something that looks remarkably 'academic' I must say.

Comment: Maybe this one is more explicit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493545/xpath-java-get-element-by-testing-value

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811101/366749) that's more applicable to your case. XPath is a convenient and easy t-to-use technology to extract the information you seek, but performance requirements may dictate otherwise.

The xpath expressions, in your case, would be, for instance::

```
"root1/root2/C/D/GetE/text()"
"root1/root2/C/D/GetF/text()"
```

But as others have commented, "root1/root2/C/D/GetE" doesn't return a single node, so you have to decide how you are going to represent the information too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a simpler way but SAXParser would do the job.