# How can I parse the xml?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

In my project, the url return the xml data,and How can I parse the xml?
[image]

Comment: read this post
[In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file)

Comment: refer http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @Sanoop, I already look the way ,it's useful for me ,but only have the `url`,and how can read the url then achieve the above black part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse data by tag.

[Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html):

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("Start document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          System.out.println("End document");
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
          System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
          System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
      } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
          System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
```