# Read a certain part of a String (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read a certain part of a String in this String:

```
    <test>3:35</test>
```

The part I want to read is 3:35, but I just can't seem to figure it out.
What I have currently is:

```
    s.skip("<test>");
    t = s.next();
    s.skip("</test>");
```

But of course, all I get back is `3:35</test>` because I skip after `t = s.next()`

Can anyone explain the way too easy solution I'm probably not seeing here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to parse XML?

Comment: In the long run, the way too easy solution is to use an XML parser.

Comment: And ugly solution could be to set the delimiter to use `<test>` or `</test>` as delimiter... but go with an XML reader instead.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I will try to use an XML parser, is there any good guide on XML parsers? they are new to me.

Comment: Use the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160 to get a Document, then traverse it

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<test>(.+?)</test>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<test>3:35</test>");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Output: 3:35
```

P.S: Regex are not the best tool to do this kind of computation, in long term  an XML parser should be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex or XML parser, you can modify your solution like this -

```
s.skip("<test>");
    t = s.next();
   t = t.substring(0,t.indexOf("</test>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex as Sachin mentioned, or by using replaceall():

```
    String str = "<test>3:35</test>"; 
    str = str.replaceAll("<test>", ""); 
    str = str.replaceAll("</test>", ""); 
    System.out.println(str);
```

Better to make a function which takes the original string and the strings that you want to replace as an argument, then return the desired value...