# how can I enhance performance of DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile)?

Tags: java, xml, string, performance, file

275

I am following this post [In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file) and made stress testing using JMeter by sending 100 request per second for a round 15 minutes and profiling using InteliJ profiler and found that `parse` method taking much time like as attached image

[image: Screenshot of Parsing time]

How can I enhance this method?

Comment: `xml.getBytes()` creates a copy of the entire XML document in memory.  Since you’re doing this often, this probably will affect performance.  You should use `new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))` instead.

Comment: @VGR yes, I failed to spot that. Also, decoding the characters to bytes using the platform default encoding rather than the encoding declared in the XML declaration means (a) you're decoding and re-encoding unnecessarily, and (b) could lead to encoding errors if the two encodings differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAXP factory methods such as `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` are expensive because they search the classpath looking for a class that provides the document-builder service. You should only call this method once in an application, at most; ideally, don't call it at all, because you only need it if you want the user of your application to be able to run it with a different (and probably untested!) document builder. Instead, decide which document builder you want to use and hard-code it.

There's probably a fair bit of initialization cost for the parser as well. Ideally, if you're parsing thousands of very small files, reuse the same parser rather than creating a new one each time. But that's a minor improvement compared with the search for a factory.