# Parse HTML links from a google query

Tags: java, html

First the revised code which throws `javax.swing.text.ChangedCharSetException`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        String query = "#pragma";
        Socket s = new Socket("google.com",80);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.print("GET /search?q="+query+" HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        p.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n");
        p.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(in);
//        String line;
//
//        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
//        {  System.out.println(line); }
        HTMLUtils.ParseLinks (buffer);
        in.close();
    }
}


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Attribute;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;

public class HTMLUtils
{
  private HTMLUtils() {}

  public static List<String> extractLinks(Reader reader) throws IOException
  {
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ParserDelegator parserDelegator = new ParserDelegator();
    ParserCallback parserCallback = new ParserCallback()
    {
      public void handleText(final char[] data, final int pos) { }
      public void handleStartTag(Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet attribute, int pos)
      {
        if (tag == Tag.A) {
          String address = (String) attribute.getAttribute(Attribute.HREF);
          list.add(address);
        }
      }
      public void handleEndTag(Tag t, final int pos) {  }
      public void handleSimpleTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, final int pos) { }
      public void handleComment(final char[] data, final int pos) { }
      public void handleError(final java.lang.String errMsg, final int pos) { }
    };
    parserDelegator.parse(reader, parserCallback, false);
    return list;
  }

  public static void ParseLinks(BufferedReader buffer) throws Exception{
    //FileReader reader = new FileReader("buffer");
    List<String> links = HTMLUtils.extractLinks(buffer);
    for (String link : links) {
      System.out.println(link);
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the user agent is for IE in this example.

Now I Have 3 problems:

1. How/can I pass the HTMLUtils.ParseLinks method a "raw buffer" instead of an HTML file she's expecting (I can write the buffer to a file but I guess that is unnecessary)
2. I don't know how to enter inverted commas (" ") inside the query statment in order to get the whole string i.e.: query=" "New York Yankees" "
3. Is it so complicated to get the User-Agent string from the host machine ???
   [link text](http://nerds.palmdrive.net/useragent/code.html)

I have to say that it is imported class that I use and I don't really understand whats going on there. I'll try to understand when it will work [-8

THNX

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/, it's going to be a lot easier to get the data out of a JSON string than digging through acres of HTML. There's an open source Java class for digesting JSON: http://www.json.org/java/. Transferring the JSON will require a lot less bandwidth too!

Comment: Hi fredley, 
I not familiar to JSON a link with a "proof of concept" to what you advised might be helpful...THNX

Comment: The great thing about it is you don't need to know how it works. Once you've retrieved your JSON String using the appropriate call, you initialize it: JSONObject j = new JSONObject(jsonString); and then everything is in a nicely formatted data structure under j, so you can make calls like:

int myInt = j.getInt['someTag'];
JSONObject[] myArray = j.getJSONArray['Results'];
String Title = myArray.getJSONObject(0).getString['title'];

All you need to do is read the docs on the api to learn the data structure, then there's only a few methods you actually need to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in Java, you should consider using XPath to extract all links from the response. Therefore you first have to [convert the response to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262/how-do-i-load-an-org-w3c-dom-document-from-xml-in-a-string). Then you can [apply an XPath](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html) query like

```
//a/@href
```

to extract all `href` attributes for links. You can modify the query to only include links from the Google results and not from advertisements etc.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) is another Tutorial to get you started.

Happy coding.

**BTW**: To avoid mistakes when you create your HTTP request and (even more important) to avoid unnecessary work, you could use a library like [Apache Commons HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). This would reduce your work to:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query);
int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
}
String response = new String(method.getResponseBody());
```

Comment: If you're going to parse HTML anyway instead of using a lightweight JSON webservice, then I'd recommend Jsoup over HttpClient. HttpClient is nice, but it gives nothing to parse HTML with. You could as good use java.net.URLConnection.

Comment: @BalusC Hey, that's cool. Haven't heard of JSoup before. Thanks for the hint.