# Getting the XSD source from an org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema object?

Tags: java, xsd, eclipse-emf

I'm parsing an XML Schema file (*.xsd) using org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema and would like to display some XSDTypeDefinitions as literal XSD source.

Here's an example schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="shiporder">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="shipto">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here's some code for illustrating the problem:

```
XSDSchema schema = loadSchemaFromFile(); // not shown
for(XSDElementDeclaration element : schema.getElementDeclarations()){
    assert element.getName().equals("shiporder");

    String xsdSource = // NOW WHAT DO I NEED TO DO HERE?

    String expectedXsdSource = "<xs:element name=\"shiporder\">" +
        "  <xs:complexType>" +
        "    <xs:sequence>" +
        "      <xs:element name=\"orderperson\" type=\"xs:string\"/>" +
        "      <xs:element name=\"shipto\">" +
        "        <xs:complexType>" +
        "          <xs:sequence>" +
        "            <xs:element name=\"address\" type=\"xs:string\"/>" +
        "          </xs:sequence>" +
        "        </xs:complexType>" +
        "      </xs:element>" +
        "  </xs:complexType>" +
        "</xs:element>";

    assert xsdSource.equals(expectedXsdSource);
}
```

I'm using the following jar files from an Eclipse 3.7 installation:

- org.eclipse.xsd_2.7.0.v20110606-0949.jar
- org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.7.0.v20110605-0747.jar
- org.eclipse.emf.common_2.7.0.v20110605-0747.jar

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two XML documents using String.equals might be hazardous as white space might differ even though it ought not affect equality.

How about using [isEqualNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#isEqualNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29)? You could convert org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema to org.w3c.dom.Document by using the [getDocument](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/xsd/javadoc/2.3.0/org/eclipse/xsd/XSDSchema.html#getDocument%28%29) method and the following [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262/how-do-i-load-an-org-w3c-dom-document-from-xml-in-a-string") to convert your schema string?