# Construct org.w3c.dom.Document from marshalled object

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I'd like to construct a `org.w3c.dom.Document` from my marshalled object.

I've tried what's described in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262/how-do-i-load-an-org-w3c-dom-document-from-xml-in-a-string) but in vain.

This is my code :

```
public Document serialise() throws Exception {
    MyClass myObjectToMarshall = this.getObjectToMarshall();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    m.marshal(myObjectToMarshall , System.out);
    StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
    m.marshal(myObjectToMarshall , xml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString())));
}
```

When this instruction `m.marshal(myObjectToMarshall , System.out);` is executed, I get the following result :

```
<myObjectToMarshall >
    <id>15</id>
    <code>MY_CODE</code>
    <label>MY_LABEL</label>
    <date>2015-09-15+02:00</date>
</myObjectToMarshall >
```

I guess the marshalling of myObjectToMarshall has been correctly done.

But, when I debug the last instruction using IntelliJ, `builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString())))`, I get a null Document : `[#document: null]`

Is there other properties to set?

Please could you help me to undestand why document is null?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm using java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Document is fine.

The `toString()` method is implemented to return `"["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]"`. The `nodeName` of a document is `#document`, and the `nodeValue` of a document is `null`. See the javadoc of [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

If you want a DOM document, don't marshal into a `String` and then parse the text. Just marshal straight into a DOM tree:

```
public Document serialise() throws Exception {
    MyClass myObjectToMarshall = this.getObjectToMarshall();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
    DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
    jc.createMarshaller().marshal(myObjectToMarshall, domResult);
    return (Document)domResult.getNode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas for you answer. Y're right it works very fine. I've parsed Document's node list. They are all there.