# Java String to XML (Document)

Tags: java, xml

I am reading XML data from a web service and storing it in an String:

```
String output;
String dataReceived = "";
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
       dataReceived = dataReceived + output;
}
```

But when I try to create a DOM Document object from the String, I get a NPE. I am following this examples:

Option 1: [How do I load an org.w3c.dom.Document from XML in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262/how-do-i-load-an-org-w3c-dom-document-from-xml-in-a-string)

Option 2: [In Java, how do I parse XML as a String instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562160/in-java-how-do-i-parse-xml-as-a-string-instead-of-a-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
public void parseXML(String dataReceived) {

//Option 1
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataReceived.getBytes()));
System.out.println(document);


//Option 2
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(dataReceived));
Document document = builder.parse(is);
System.out.println(document);

}
```

But as I said I get a NPE. Why?

```
[#document: null]
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATE:**
I print the received String at the beginning of parseXML function and this is what I get

Received data: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GeocodeResponse> <status>OK</status> <result>  <type>street_address</type>  <formatted_address>Calle de José Abascal, 1, 28003 Madrid, Spain</formatted_address>  <address_component>   <long_name>1</long_name>   <short_name>1</short_name>   <type>street_number</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>Calle de José Abascal</long_name>   <short_name>Calle de José Abascal</short_name>   <type>route</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>Madrid</long_name>   <short_name>Madrid</short_name>   <type>locality</type>   <type>political</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>Madrid</long_name>   <short_name>M</short_name>   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>   <type>political</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>Comunidad de Madrid</long_name>   <short_name>Comunidad de Madrid</short_name>   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>   <type>political</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>Spain</long_name>   <short_name>ES</short_name>   <type>country</type>   <type>political</type>  </address_component>  <address_component>   <long_name>28003</long_name>   <short_name>28003</short_name>   <type>postal_code</type>  </address_component>  <geometry>   <location>    <lat>40.4387423</lat>    <lng>-3.7022840</lng>   </location>   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>   <viewport>    <southwest>     <lat>40.4373933</lat>     <lng>-3.7036330</lng>    </southwest>    <northeast>     <lat>40.4400913</lat>     <lng>-3.7009350</lng>    </northeast>   </viewport>  </geometry>  <partial_match>true</partial_match>  <place_id>ChIJP58jD_YoQg0RPwBTvmkE2qQ</place_id> </result></GeocodeResponse>`

**UPDATE 2:**

As minus has said that is not the part that launches the NPE. It is the following code. I have thought as when printing `System.out.println(document);` it shows null, maybe the parse was erroneous. I will take a look at this code. Thanks.

```
 XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

   Node nodeLat = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//geometry/location/lat",
                        document, XPathConstants.NODE);
   Node nodeLng = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//geometry/location/lng",
                        document, XPathConstants.NODE);

   System.out.println("n " + nodeLat);
   latLong[0] = Double.parseDouble(nodeLat.getNodeValue());
   latLong[1] = Double.parseDouble(nodeLng.getNodeValue());
```

**UPDATE 3**

Just BTW The correct way to read the node's value is:

```
String expression = "//geometry/location/lat";
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println("latitude: " + node.getTextContent());
```

And thanks again

Comment: Have you printed out `dataReceived` to verify it's populated? If it is, try just translating that to XML via a file and see if it's valid.

Comment: @Dan W, yes, the String is populated. OK, I will try

Comment: give an example of input that fails.

Comment: @njzk Updated with an exmple of a String that fails

Comment: By the way; `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Looks like debugging is needed. Check that you close things too, check the line of the NPE; is it really on document.

Comment: `[#document: null]` is a document and not a null reference, so your parse succeeded, post the exact line which throws the NPE.

Comment: Instead of storing the XML in a String, why not just create an InputSource from your original Reader and parse that into a Document?

Comment: @minus. Oh, you are right. I updated the question with the code that launches the error (when trying to convert null value to double) and why I though the parse was erroneous

Comment: @minus. But it isn't strange that when I print the document it shows null?

Comment: Your parse is correct and your XML is a `FirstChild` of `Document`, not `document` it-self. Check what is in `document.getFirstChild()` - your XML   is there.